# Maintain speed, in 3D game, after collision in Unity

Tags: unity, collision-detection, physics

I am making a simple breakout game. I have added bounce physics to the ball and to the bricks. When the ball collides with the bricks, the speed of ball slows down. I want ball to maintain its speed to what I set it to intially.

Comment: What have you tried? Why didn't it work? Show your relevant code. We can't guess what's going wrong.

Comment: Is there a way of changing speed of the ball at any time? I want to change the speed after collision.

Comment: This is a great place to implement atan2. Here's a video that describes how to achieve this in great detail: https://youtu.be/u_p5H0wEN8Y

Comment: @Mike You can do this without trigonometry. `ball.velocity = ball.velocity.normalized * speed` suffices.

Answer (score 1):

Set a new [Physics Material](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicMaterial.html) on both the ball and the object you are colliding with.  Make sure you set the Friction parameters to 0 and Bounciness to 1.

(Alternatively, you can apply the material to just one side of the collision, with the Combine parameters set to "Maximum" so it overrides the material of anything it collides with)

Comment: Done already. Speed is still changing.